# Passar parâmetro no Bundle

Tags: java, jsf

Minha aplicação usa a internacionalização de mensagens, etc. Eu gostaria de saber como faço pra passar parâmetros na hora de passar uma chave que vai buscar um valor no arquivo .properties. Ex:

Minhas telas de crud vão sempre exibir uma mensagem de sucesso quando for feito um novo cadastro. A mensagem padrão seria: **Produdo cadastrado(a) com sucesso!**. A palavra **Produto** pode variar já o restante pode ser fixo. Então no meu arquivo .properties está assim:

```
pruduto=Produto
cadastro.sucesso= {0} cadastrado(a) com sucesso!
```

Ou seja sempre virá algum valor antes da chave `cadastro.sucesso`. Atualmente meu código está assim:

```
package br.com.pokemax.util;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class MensagensUtil {

    private final static ResourceBundle BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties.mensagens", new Locale("pt"));;

    public static String recupera(String chave) {
        return BUNDLE.getString(chave);
    }

    public static void sucesso(String mensagem) {

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, recupera(mensagem), "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", msg);
    }

    public static void erro(String mensagem) {

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, recupera(mensagem), "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", msg);
    }

    public static void alerta(String mensagem) {

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, recupera(mensagem), "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", msg);
    }

}
```

Nesta situação eu preciso passar uma chave apenas, etc. Como posso fazer pra aceitar passar parâmetros ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai usar a função [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) pra isso.
Por exemplo ao invés de usar:

```
public static void sucesso(String mensagem) {

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, recupera(mensagem), "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", msg);
    }
```

Você vai escrever assim:

```
public static void sucesso(String mensagem, Object... parametros) {

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, String.format(recupera(mensagem), parametros), "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", msg);
    }
```

Só mais uma dica, você está repetindo muito código nessa classe, veja que os métodos sucesso, erro e alerta fazem quase a mesma coisa, só mudando o nível de severidade. Você poderia ter um método privado que esses métodos chamariam, passando a mais apenas o nível.

Comment: Como passo o parâmetro na chamada do método? Fiz assim e não deu certo:  `MensagensUtil.sucesso("cadastro.sucesso","geracao");`

Comment: Você chamou corretamente, mostrou algum erro?

Comment: No seu método ele não conseguiu achar o valor da chave, eu consegui utilizando uma outra maneira que vou postar abaixo, mesmo assim obrigado pela sua dedicação.

Comment: Ele não encontra o valor da chave :/

Comment: Não encontrava antes? Pq a ideia é não mudar a busca da chave, apenas adicionar os parâmetros depois.